# python: rotate an array 90 degree - but not symetric dimension

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, rotation

I am implementing a game which uses blocks, that contain of pixels.

I want to be able to rotate those blocks.
Therefore I began to use this nice line:

```
self.array = zip(*self.array[::-1])
```

But as it turns out, I can't turn an array of `2x3` to `3x2` and back
I start with the array: `2x3`, then I rotate it to `3x2` but then never come back to `2x3` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[list(row) for row in zip(*self.array[::-1])]
```